# Aspire V5-531 Operating System Not Found

Tags: linux, windows, boot

I recently purchased an Acer Aspire V5-531.  I replaced the 320GB HDD with a 120GB Kingston SSDNow V200 and installed Linux booting with rEFInd.

Due to a necessary change, I have to move back to Windows on this machine.  However upon partitioning the drive, the system froze.  After rebooting, I now get the error "Operating System not found".

I've tried using <kbd>F12</kbd> (alternative boot method) and <kbd>F2</kbd> (BIOS) - both return the same error.

Anyone have any ideas how I might resolve this?  I've tried unplugging the BIOS battery for 30 seconds, to no effect.

Rather lost, stuck and confused!

Comment: Wait, you put the original drive (with Windows on it) back into the system, then **repartitioned it**?  When you did that you effectively deleted Windows.

Comment: I know this, however I have a Windows 8 USB key to reinstall.  The problem isn't a lack of Windows - the problem is that I can't access the BIOs or boot menu.  *Everything* redirects to the aforementioned error.  Merely missing Windows isn't a problem.  Also I didn't replace the original drive with the SSD.  The SSD is still installed.

Comment: So the SSD is still the boot drive? Please clarify. Also, are you saying you can't even get to the BIOS configuration screen? Have you tried ESC and DEL as well as F2? Is there a BIOS prompt (i.e. "Press DEL to configure BIOS" or something similar?)

Comment: SSD is the boot drive.  F2 is to access BIOS, F12 to access boot menu.  Neither keys produce any output, neither does DEL or ESC.  I've tried unplugging the CMOS battery to clear the BIOS, to no effect.  To clarify, I can't access BIOS or boot menu.

Comment: Ouch! Something is seriously wrong, but... Check the keyboard -- make sure it's plugged in, try a different keyboard.  If it's wireless, try using a wired keyboard.  If it's wired and USB, plug it into a different USB port.

Comment: It's a laptop, though I did try an external keyboard... Both "respond" in term of the error flashes to a keypress... But still nothing other than "Operating System not found" error.  To also clarify... Pressing "F2" at the BIOS splash produces "Please Wait", before returning the aforementioned error.

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  If you cannot get into the BIOS, maybe the BIOS itself got corrupted. If the laptop manufacturer provides a diagnostic CD maybe you could try putting that in the drive before you power on.  Maybe it will boot off the diagnostic CD.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is over 10 years old and has no clear answer nor do I think the original poster actually cares about this topic anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set BIOS to AHCI mode. Had the same problem with mine.

Comment: I doubt that. With AHCI or legacy mode incorret the system should find an OS and then fail. OP gets an error before that.